# Why should removeListener() method take argument according to JavaBeans Standards?

Tags: java, ejb, listener

I understand why `addXXXListener()` take an argument. But why is it in the `removeXXXListener()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're passing the method a specific listener to remove.  When you add a listener it gets added to a set.  If you want to remove it, you have to tell the object which listener to remove from the set.

From the [JavaBeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html):

> Invoking the `add<ListenerType>` method adds the given listener to the set of event listeners registered for events associated with the `<ListenerType>`. Similarly invoking the `remove<ListenerType>` method removes the given listener from the set of event listeners registered for events associated with the `<ListenerType>`.